# Re-enabling the submit button after a timeout

Tags: php, javascript, submit

The submit_pdf button saves up the information into the database and to avoid multiple clicks, i initially had disabled the submit button after one click, however now i would like to re enable the button after a timeout of 10 seconds. The part till where the submit button gets disabled is working fine, but if i try to add a delay of 10 seconds, it doesn't seem to work.It would be really helpful if you could help me out with this.

```
        echo '  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        window.open(\'./index_pdf.php?'.$query_string.'\',\'Warehouse_ST\',\'location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no\');
        id_form.submit_pdf.disabled=true;
        window.alert("Data is stored in the database, Please do no click on Submit again without changing any information");

        window.addEvent(\'domready''\',function() 
        {
        var subber = $_REQUEST["submit_pdf"];
        subber.addEvent( \'click'  ,function() ' 
        {
         subber.set( \'value','Submitting...''\' ).disabled = true;
        (function() { subber.disabled = false; subber.set(\'value','submit_pdf'\'); }).delay(10000); // how much time?  10 seconds
        });
        });


        //]]>
        </script>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

define a function to enable the button, and then set a setTimeout():

```
function enableButton(){
    $('#myButton').attr("disabled", false);
}

setTimeout(enableButton, 10000);
```

make sure to put the function name without quotes and without the "()"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to write JS code (aleation 's code is correct) and this PHP code.

PHP (store the time in a session var):

```
session_start(); //At the beginning of the PHP file

define("TIMEOUT", 10); //10 sec

//Check timeout
if (isset($_SESSION['expire'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['expire']-time()>TIMEOUT) {
        unset($_SESSION['expire']);
    }   
}

//Allow to do submit after 10 sec
if (!isset($_SESSION['expire'])) {
    $_SESSION['expire']=time();

    //Your submit code
}
```

This is because user can manipulate JavaScript and HTTP messages, but he/she can't manipulate php code.